# iOS. Empty image sets in before the image completely downloaded while starting app

Tags: iphone, xcode, download, uiimage, reload

My app displays photo feed on start up just like Instagram.
My problem is app shows empty image(for cells) property before it completely downloaded.

When I scrolled down the view and again scroll up(make some of cells invisible and then make visible by scrolling), then the cell images shows up!

Method for setting cells are like this..

```
- (AQGridViewCell *)gridView: (AQGridView *)aGridView cellForItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger)index {
    static NSString *PlainCellIdentifier = @"PlainCellIdentifier";

    GridViewCell *cell = (GridViewCell *)[aGridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlainCellIdentifier"];

    if ( cell == nil ) {
        cell = [[GridViewCell alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 74, 74)
                                   reuseIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier];
    }


    [cell.captionLabel setText:text];

    [cell.imageView setImage:image];

    return cell;
}
```

What can I do for the [setImage:] method to wait for image to complete, or showing downloading image, or reload automatically?

Comment: for me, for you http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Web Image
This library provides a category for UIImageVIew with support for remote images coming from the web.

It provides:

An UIImageView category adding web image and cache management to the Cocoa Touch framework
An asynchronous image downloader
An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling
A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times
A guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again
Performances!